# Remover tag local no Git

Tags: git, html-tags

Como faço para deletar uma tag que foi criada localmente no meu repositório git e ainda não foi "pushada"

Exemplo:

Criei a tag `v1.4.9`, mas reparei que estava no branch errado antes de fazer `git push`. Quero remover a tag `v1.4.9` que está criada localmente.

Comment: use a linha de comando abaixo, segundo o github

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
$ git tag -d v1.4.9
```

ou seja `$ git tag` e juntas `-d` para apagar ou `-a` para adicionar seguido da *string* da tag

Comment: perfeito, muito obrigado!

Comment: @jpklzm se a resposta do usuário atendeu sua dúvida, por favor marque a resposta dele como correta.

Comment: O sistema estava me impedindo de marcar a resposta como correta. Me pedia para aguardar 15 minutos e eu acabei não tendo como voltar.