# Como deletar múltiplas (muitas) tags no Git de maneira prática?

Tags: git

Em nosso repositório central no GitHub, estamos atualmente desenvolvendo e mantendo a versão `v2.x.x` do projeto e resolvemos remover as todas as tags da versão `v1.x.x` e manter apenas a ultima versão *patch* da v1 que no nosso caso é a `1.8.12`.

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42176/95771) é demonstrado como remover **uma tag** com o comando:

> `$ git tag -d v1.4.9`

E acrescentando a resposta, para remover a tag do repositório remoto, usamos o comando:

```
$ git push --delete origin v1.4.9
```

Porém, esse comando pode ser usado para **uma ou algumas tags**:

```
$ git tag -d v1.4.9 v1.4.8 ....
```

Isso não é muito prático quando se deseja remover muitas tags. No meu caso, temos por volta de umas 32 tags desde a primeira versão `0.1.0` até a ultima versão *patch* `1.8.12`.

- Como remover múltiplas (muitas) tags de maneira fácil?
- No exemplo, como remover, de maneira prática, desde a tag `0.1.0` até a tag `1.8.11` e fazer o `push` de remoção para o repositório remoto?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer é gerar a lista de tags a serem apagadas, e em seguida passá-las para o `git`.

Por exemplo, no Linux (ou no Git Bash do Windows) daria para fazer algo do tipo:

```bash
git tag -d $(git tag -l "v0.*.*" "v1.[0-9].*" "v1.1[0-8].*")
```

No caso, o comando `git tag -l` lista as tags cujos nomes batam com o padrão informado. Segundo a [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt--l), o *wildcard* segue o padrão usado por [`fnmatch`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html) (que é mesmo descrito [aqui](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)). Basicamente, um `*` significa "zero ou mais caracteres" e os colchetes definem um conjunto de caracteres.

Portanto, o comando acima está listando as tags que satisfazem um dos critérios:

- `"v0.*.*"`: começa com `v0.`, assim, pega as versões desde a `v0.0.0` até a `v0.9999999.etc`

  - Caso existam as versões `v0.0.*` e você só queira da `v0.1.0` em diante, pode mudar para `"v0.[1-9].*" "v0.[1-9][0-9].*"` (o primeiro pega da `v0.1.*` até `v0.9.*`, e o segundo pega da `v0.10.*` em diante)
- `"v1.[0-9].*"`: começa com `v1.`, depois tem **apenas** um dígito de 0 a 9 (assim eu evito que pegue, por exemplo, `v1.20.*`), e depois tem um ponto e "qualquer coisa". Assim, essa parte só pega de `v1.0.*` até `v1.9.*`
- `"v1.1[0-8].*"`: começa com `v1.1`, depois tem um dígito de 0 a 8, assim pega de `v1.10.*` até `v1.18.*` (se tiver tags `v1.19.*`, elas ficam de fora)

Se não quiser apagar todas as tags `v1.18.*` aí tem ser mais específico, por exemplo:

- trocar por `"v1.1[0-7].*` para pegar de `v1.10.*` até `v1.17.*`
- e adicionar `"v1.18.[0-9]"` para pegar até a `v1.18.9`

  - se quer que pegue também, por exemplo, de `v1.18.10` até `v1.18.13`, bastaria adicionar `"v1.18.1[0-3]"` na lista de critérios, e assim por diante. Quanto mais específico, mais <strike>chato</strike> critérios precisa colocar

E claro que, se quiser simplesmente tudo que for `v0.*` ou `v1.*`, bastaria usar `"v[0-1].*"`.

Infelizmente não tem uma forma simples de tratar as tags como intervalos numéricos (então nada de ter algo como `v0.0.0 < versão < v1.18.10`). Afinal, tags são apenas nomes (strings), e você pode defini-las como quiser. O fato de podermos usar números de versão no formato `x.y.z` é um mero detalhe, mas mesmo os dígitos são tratados como meros caracteres (tanto que a saída do comando mostra elas em [ordem lexicográfica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440503/112052), e não numérica).

---

Por fim, uma vez definidos os critérios, a saída de `git tag -l` é passada para `git tag -d` (através da sintaxe de [command substitution](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/327578/112052) - o `$(  )` em volta do comando), que apaga as tags.

---

No caso de precisar fazer o `push` para apagá-las também no repositório remoto, basta apagar primeiro remotamente, e depois localmente:

```bash
# apaga no repositório remoto
git push -d origin $(git tag -l "v0.*.*" "v1.[0-9].*" "v1.1[0-8].*")
# apaga localmente
git tag -d $(git tag -l "v0.*.*" "v1.[0-9].*" "v1.1[0-8].*")
```

Se fizer o oposto (primeiro apaga localmente), não vai funcionar, porque ao apagar localmente, o `git tag -l` não vai mais encontrar as tags.

Ou ainda, para evitar rodar o mesmo comando duas vezes, pode-se salvar os nomes das tags em um arquivo:

```bash
# salva os nomes das tags em um arquivo
git tag -l "v0.*.*" "v1.[0-9].*" "v1.1[0-8].*" > tags
# apaga no repositório remoto
git push -d origin $(cat tags)
# apaga localmente
git tag -d $(cat tags)

# opcional, apagar o arquivo
rm tags
```

Ou salvar os nomes em uma variável:

```bash
# salva os nomes das tags na variável "tags"
tags=$(git tag -l "v0.*.*" "v1.[0-9].*" "v1.1[0-8].*")
# apaga no repositório remoto
git push -d origin $tags
# apaga localmente
git tag -d $tags

# opcional, remover a variável
unset tags
```

Comment: _"Se fizer o oposto (primeiro apaga localmente), não vai funcionar, porque ao apagar localmente, o git tag -l não vai mais encontrar as tags."_ Não sei se vale uma pergunta, mas poderíamos usar algum comando do git (que eu não conheço) para listar as tags remotamente e depois só adaptar o código `git push -d origin $(git tag -l "v0.*.*" "v1.[0-9].*" "v1.1[0-8].*")`?

Comment: @CmteCardeal  Para listar tags remotas, use `git ls-remote --tags origin` mas ele mostra mais do que somente as tags (mostra também o hash do commit). Então no seu caso teria que ser algo como `git push -d origin $( git ls-remote --tags origin "v0.*.*" "v1.[0-9].*" "v1.1[0-8].*" | cut -f2 | sed 's/refs\/tags\///g' )` - o `cut` e `sed` é para limpar a saída do comando e ter somente o nome das tags (fiz num teste rápido aqui, rode somente o git ls-remote pra ver se ele traz o que precisa)